# Multiple apps with composer

Tags: php, deployment, frameworks, composer-php

There is a main application, let's call it APP.

APP has several dependencies (including open source projects and proprietary libraries).

There are multiple clients that use their own instance of APP (on different domains that I manage). Some of these clients use a slightly adjusted version of APP. I implemented this by creating a specific module (let's call it SM) for each client that I just add to their instance of APP (so that I don't change any of the code from APP).

Currently, I've implemented this as follows:

- Develop APP locally, use Composer to update its dependencies (`composer update`), `push` APP on central repo
- For each regular client, `pull` APP from central repo and install the Composer dependencies (`composer install`)
- For clients with specific implementation, create a new SM (specific module), that has the following `composer.json` file:

  ```
  ...
  "require": {
      "APP": "X.X.X"
  } 
  ...
  ```

Then apply the same steps as before for this SM (`composer update` locally, `PUSH` to central repo, `PULL` from central repo, `composer install`).

Everything is fine, except for two issues that I'd like to overcome:

1. `composer.lock` from APP will be ignored by SM (since APP is loaded as a library in the `vendor/` folder, and composer ignores the `composer.lock` files of libraries); this is not good at all, as I will not be confident that the specific clients will use the exact same libraries as APP.
2. Each time I fix a bug or implement a new feature in APP (and this happens frequently - a few times a day), apart from the steps that I perform for the regular clients, I also need to rebuild the SMs (since one of their libraries - APP - was updated to a new version that I need to use). This is an overhead since most of the changes that I perform are inside APP (and not SM). So, if it was the other way (APP having SM as a dependency), it would have been working faster (since I wouldn't need to `composer update` on each SM).

Are there any known workflows or best practices that cover this scenario in order to mitigate the two issues above or at least to decrease the complexity of the upgrade/deployment process?

*Please note that most of the steps above are already automated, so my question is not about the automation part, but the complexity of this architecture*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I implemented this by creating a specific module (let's call it SM) for each client that I just add to their instance of APP
>
> For clients with specific implementation, create a new SM (specific module), that has the following composer.json file:

It's an application with a client specific module (next to other dependencies).

The application has the module as dependency (APP having SM as a dependency).

And **not**: the module pulls the application as it's vendor dependency in.
This will only cause extra steps to take during the development phase (your issue 2).

I would suggest to refactor the application and it's modules until you get the following folder structure:

```
|-application             #< the application has dependencies
  |-src
  |-tests
  |-vendor
    |-framework           #< maybe your application is framework based
    |-libs                #< more dependencies
    |-...                 #< other modules
    |-sm                  #< the client specific module
```

This allows to pull in dependencies, which extend "the application" for client-specific needs.

This overcomes your issue 1, because APP is the main repository and contains the lock file. It's essential to lock the versions, so that all developers are bound to the same versions and also for packaging exactly the same set of versions.

> So, if it was the other way (APP having SM as a dependency), it would have been working faster (since I wouldn't need to composer update on each SM).

Yes! The need to rebuild the module, each time you change APP would vanish, if you start to "develop inside APP" with module dependencies.

---

And for multiple clients, simply use multiple application repos, which have a custom set of requirements. 10 clients, 10 application repos, 10 composer.json files. Run `composer install no-dev` then pre-package each repo and place zip into downloads. Done.

You can use a "container" or "packaging" project here, where the `composer.json` of each project would include the app and the specific modules. You might utilize the caret or tilde operator to specify a version range for the app (`"vendor/app": "^1.2.3"`) and then simply `update` and `repackage`, after a new version of the application is released. This approach should work with the composer autoloading, because the application will remain inside the vendor folder, too. Only a little wrapper is needed, to set the composer autoloader up and switch over to your application.

Or, if the application is really modular. Just package the main application and provide the client-specific modules as extra downloads. With this approach upgrades will have multiple download steps: upgrade app, upgrade modules. Think of it as "wordpress-style" updates/upgrades.

---

You might reduce the complexity of the upgrade/deployment process further by dropping the `composer install --no-dev` part on the client machine
by building "client-specific application archives" on the developer machine.
These are basically the "--no-dev" package of the application with all it's dependencies, including the client-specific module(s) = pre-packaged.

Like, `Application-v1.2.3-WithModuleAForClientA-v3.2.1.zip`.

On the dev machine: `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader` + `zip`.

To install or upgrade simply `download` to the client, `extract`, execute the `upgrade` script. Done.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into elaborating this answer. The only thing that was keeping me from using a project where APP requires the specific module was that I had to create a separate bundle with the prepacked APP and the SM. In my ideal scenario I could keep the APP separate from the SM and then just update the installation on the production server (just like having two composer.lock files in the same folder).

Comment: Also, regarding your suggestion for multiple application repos, wouldn't it mean that each time I PUSH a bugfix to the APP repo, I should also synchronize all the other repos, as well? (and only after that, deploy those repos to each production domain); I would have preferred a single PUSH to a central repo and then just a PULL from all the client domains.

Comment: Yes, the applications repos need to be synced - to get the bugfix (propably as a patch on top of them). Or you could switch something like a "container" or "packaging" project, which would contain the application itself as a dependency. The composer.json of this project would include the app and the specific modules. You might utilize the caret or tilde operator to specify a version range for the app (`"vendor/app": "^1.2.3"`) and simply update and repackage.